# how can i fill the search filter lul with the clicked on li option , and place it in the search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML search filter:

```
<ul id="listExperts" class="ui-inline" 
    data-role="listview" 
    data-filter="true" 
    data-filter-reveal="true" 
    data-filter-placeholder="Search Expert" 
    data-filter-value="Search Expert" data-inset="true">
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).on('click','#listExperts li',function(){
    expertID = $(this).attr('expertID');
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(expertID);
    console.log(name);
    document.getElementById('RemoveExpertLabel').innerHTML = expertID;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8oqLwpL5/) this will help your course.

```
$('li.inliner').on('click',function(){
var content= $(this).text();
$('#MySearchBox').val(content);
  });
```

This might help you .